# Return pointer from type and string of name

Tags: c++, qt

How would I return a(n existing) pointer to a known type from a string of its name? Say I created some `map<string, double>` called `map1` and some `vector<string>` called `vec1`. I'd like to write a function that will return `map1` from `"map1"` and `vec1` from `"vec1"` (and an additional argument specifying the respective type of each).

Is this possible?

My ultimate goal is to get a `QWidget` by its name in `QString` form, since I'm working with a large number of them, though an answer should be framework-independent, right?

Comment: You're getting into debug information territory, here (if you want to properly handle scope, etc.). Why not just write a simple object registry yourself?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do.

Comment: This can be done (presumably someone will answer soon), but I suspect there's a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: You can store a [`type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) or `type_info*` in a container, but before I start writing an answer that will never be accepted, I too would like to know why you'd need this.

Comment: MY first thought was to make derived classes with a private "name" property, but some `QWidgets` protect against inheriting.

Comment: `QObject` (and therefore `QWidget`) already supports this.  Note this is entirely impossible for general C++ objects - you have to provide the name string to the code, not just declare it.

Comment: "I suspect there's a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do." Definitely. That you wish to do it at all is a sign that your code's design is rotten.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some kind of dynamic dispatch. To do so you can simply start with exactly what you proposed:

```
enum class types { A = 0, B = 1 };
void (*handlers[])(void*) = { &HandleA, &HandleB };

::std::unordered_map<::std::string, ::std::tuple<types, void*>> registry;
```

Now all that remains is to perform the lookup:

```
void lookup(::std::string const& name)
{
    auto& t = registry.at(name);
    handlers[static_cast<size_t>(::std::get<0>(t))](::std::get<1>(t));
}
```

#### Automagic argument casting for handlers

The handlers all take an argument of type `void*` - this can be dealt with by adding a little template magic:

```
template<typename T, void(*f)(T*)>
void handle(void* arg)
{
    f(static_cast<T*>(arg));
}

void (*handlers[])(void*) = { &handle<A, &HandleA>, &handle<B, &HandleB> };
```

Now, the prototype is e.g. `void HandleA(A*)`.

#### Simple adding of objects to registry

With the current code, you can add objects to your registry like so:

```
A a;
registry.emplace("A #1", ::std::make_tuple(types::A, &a));
```

While this works perfectly, we would like to do something a bit more elegant. Let us start by changing the `enum class types` to something which also knows about the type we whish to represent it:

```
template<typename T> struct types;
template<> struct types<A> { static const size_t id = 0; };
template<> struct types<B> { static const size_t id = 1; };
```

Of course, now we need to fix the registry type:

```
::std::unordered_map<::std::string, ::std::tuple<size_t, void*>> registry;
```

And finally we can provide a simple insert function:

```
template<typename T>
void insert(::std::string const& name, T* object)
{
    registry.emplace(name, ::std::make_tuple(types<T>::id, static_cast<void*>(object)));
}
```

#### Final usage example

```
A a;
insert("A #1", &a);
lookup("A #1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The meta-object system already handles this, so the answer will be framework-specific because you generally need a code generator to get metadata about the C++ types that's not otherwise available.

```
QLineEdit * ed = ...;
ed->setObjectName("myObject");

... elsewhere in the code

foreach(QWidget * w, QCoreApplication::allWidgets()) {
  // Lookup by name
  if (w->objectName() == "myObject") {
    ...
  }
  // Lookup by type
  if (qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(w)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you want to speed up the lookup, and the objects have unique names:

```
class Widgets {
  typedef QMap<QString, QPointer<QWidget>> Data;
  mutable Data m_map;
public:
  Widgets() {
    foreach(QWidget * w, QCoreApplication::allWidgets()) {
      if (w->objectName().isEmpty()) continue;
      m_map.insert(w->objectName(), w);
    }
  }
  QWidget * lookupWidget(const QString & name) const {
    Data::iterator it = m_map.find(name);
    if (it == m_map.end()) return nullptr;
    QWidget * w = it->data();
    if (!w) m_map.erase(it); // The widget doesn't exist anymore
    return w;
  }
  template <typename T> T * lookup(const QString & name) const {
    return qobject_cast<T*>(lookupWidget(name));
  }
  void setName(QWidget * w, const QString & name) {
    Q_ASSERT(! name.isEmpty());
    w->setObjectName(name);
    m_map.insert(name, w);
  }
};
```

In your code, use `widgets->setName()` instead of `setObjectName`.

If you want to look-up by both name and type, where duplicate names are OK as long as they are all of different types:

```
class Widgets2 {
  typedef QPair<QString, QString> Key;
  typedef QMap<Key, QPointer<QWidget>> Data;
  mutable Data m_map;
  static Key keyFor(QWidget * w) {
    return qMakePair(w->objectName(),
      QString::fromLatin1(w->metaObject()->className()));
public:
  Widgets2() {
    foreach(QWidget * w, QCoreApplication::allWidgets()) {
      if (w->objectName().isEmpty()) continue;
      m_map.insert(keyFor(w), w);
    }
  }
  QWidget * lookupWidget(const QString & name, const QString & type) const {
    Data::iterator it = m_map.find(qMakePair(name, type));
    if (it == m_map.end()) return nullptr;
    QWidget * w = it->data();
    if (!w) m_map.erase(it); // The widget doesn't exist anymore
    return w;
  }
  template <typename T> T * lookup(const QString & name) const 
  {
    return qobject_cast<T*>(lookupWidget(name, 
      QString::fromLatin1(T::staticMetaObject.className())));
  }
  void setName(QWidget * w, const QString & name) {
    Q_ASSERT(! name.isEmpty());
    w->setObjectName(name);
    m_map.insert(keyFor(w), w);
  }
};
```

The lookup works as follows:

```
widgets2->lookup<QLineEdit>("myObject")->setText("foo");
```

I'm leveraging the `QObject` and `QPointer` to make the widget registry safe to widget deletions - you won't ever get a dangling pointer back.

It is also possible to track object name changes, if you so wish: `QObject` emits the `objectNameChanged` signal.

**All of this is of course a horrible hack around a broken design of your code. The fact that you need this means that you're very tightly coupling business logic and the GUI. You should use some kind of model-view architecture.**